# How to prevent credential stealing of customers via phishing and domain squatting

Tags: phishing, typosquatting

Threat actors are creating lookalike domains (ex. Telecom.com to te1ecom.com), and using those to phish users for credentials (not employees). They’re getting the MFA tokens, too.

What could be done so that the client-side code couldn’t be copied to create a replica or any other watermarking technique to let the user know that the site is genuine, without relying on client-side code?

We’ve tried buying all the lookalike domains so that no one can register them but it doesn’t seem to be working effectively.

Comment: Use a MFA method which is bound to the domain and thus prevents grabbing the credentials on a typo squatted domain. TOTP etc don't, WebAuthn does.

Comment: Why do you want to visually modify client-side code? That's not where your power lies.

Comment: Consider that you are not the only one to be concerned about this. It used to be that if you saw the green lock in the corner, then you were likely on a "real" site, but that's not true any more. If it were possible to "certify" a site as legitimate, then don't you think you would see that everywhere? Banks? Big stores? etc. There is only so much you can do to protect your customers from the actions of a 3rd party.

Answer (score 1):

Use Passkey or U2F/FIDO2/WebAuthN MFA — those will only work with the correct domain, not with a lookalike, and don’t give the attacker credentials that they can pass on to the real website.

Comment: Normal users aren't very likely to buy a U2F or Fido device...

Comment: @ThoriumBR Normal users are quite likely to do so, given that a smartphone can be used as a FIDO key (in some circumstances). It’s true that security and usability are in conflict, but it was ever so, and you must choose which is more important to you.

Comment: No, they are not... It's trivial to setup OTP in the phone and few users do. Setting up your phone as a hardware key is not as easy. We are biased because we work on security, but the average user don't even know what is a 2FA and never heard of password manager, let alone be willing to buy or setup a hardware key.